# python wx speedmeter working as clock

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I want to move hand of speedmeter (in 'wx' package) in Python with every second (same like clock) after click on a button. Action sequence would be like:
1. Click on a button
2. Hand of speedmeter starts moving after every 0.4 seconds.
But after clicking on button (to start hand of speedmeter), color of frame goes dim (seems as app is crashed but actually there is no error or exception). I think it is happening because I am writing an infinite loop (to update hand of speedmeter) which is blocking APP.MainLoop() function. And I also think that thread programming can help me but I don't know much about thread programming. So, help me for this.

Following is my code:

```
import threading
import os
import wx.lib.agw.speedmeter as SM
import wx.lib.agw.speedmeter as SM2
import sys
import wx
import math
from wx import animate
import time
from random import randint
import thread

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
        # creation frame
        l, h = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,-1,title,size=(l, h))

        self.speed = SM.SpeedMeter(self,agwStyle=SM.SM_DRAW_HAND|SM.SM_DRAW_SECTORS|SM.SM_DRAW_MIDDLE_TEXT|SM.SM_DRAW_SECONDARY_TICKS,pos=(15,10),size=(l/2,h/2))

        # Set The Region Of Existence Of SpeedMeter 1
        #self.speed.SetAngleRange(*-math.pi/4, math.pi/1.75)
        #self.speed.SetAngleRange(-2*math.pi/4, 2.57*math.pi/1.75)
        self.speed.SetAngleRange(-2*math.pi/4, 2.57*math.pi/1.75)

        # SpeedMeter In Sectors
        intervals = range(0, 5100, 100)
        self.speed.SetIntervals(intervals)

        # Assign The Same Colours To All Sectors
        colours = [wx.WHITE]*50
        self.speed.SetIntervalColours(colours)

        # Assign The Ticks
        ticks = [str(interval) for interval in intervals]
        self.speed.SetTicks(ticks)

        # Set The Ticks/Tick Markers Colour
        self.speed.SetTicksColour(wx.RED)

        # We Want To Draw 5 Secondary Ticks Between The Principal Ticks
        self.speed.SetNumberOfSecondaryTicks(4)

        # Set The Font For The Ticks Markers
        self.speed.SetTicksFont(wx.Font(8.9, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL))

        # Set The Text In The Center Of SpeedMeter
        self.speed.SetMiddleText("Actual")

        # Assign The Colour To The Center Text
        self.speed.SetMiddleTextColour(wx.BLACK)

        # Assign A Font To The Center Text
        self.speed.SetMiddleTextFont(wx.Font(22, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))

        # Set The Colour For The Hand Indicator
        self.speed.SetHandColour(wx.BLUE)#wx.Colour(255, 250, 20))

        # Do Not Draw The External (CONTAINER) Arc
        self.speed.DrawExternalArc(True)

        # adding button
        self.btn = wx.Button(self,2,"OK", pos = (400, 820), size = (50, 30))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClicked)

    def OnClicked(self, event):
        try:
            i = 0
            while(True):
                #r = randint(0, 5000)
                if(i >= 5000):
                    i = 0
                i += 50
                self.speed.SetSpeedValue(i)
                time.sleep(0.5)
        except Exception, err:
            print("Exception", Exception, err)

if __name__=='__main__' :
    APP=wx.App()
    frame=MyFrame(None,0,'Appsy')
    APP.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    APP.MainLoop()
```